# Adding Json.Net to a Unity3D project

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I added the Json.Net library to Visual Studio 2013 via NuGetpackage and installed it for NetFramework 4.5. I don't get an error in Visual Studio when I add

`using Newtonsoft.Json;`

but in Unity3D 5.0 I get the error:

> Assets/RobotController.cs(5,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace
>   name `Newtonsoft' could not be found. Are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?

I looked up in my packages folders for this project and the dll file is there, so I don't understand the problem. Thx for help.

Comment: did you try a rebuild?

Comment: Try to place *.dll into the Assets/Plugins folder.

Comment: So apparently the target Framework was still 3.5. After I chose the right .dll file I had no error when I rebuilt the project in Visual Studio(had several warnings, when I chose the wrong one). If I copy the .dll file from the packages folder for NET 3.5 I get this error:
Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: The classes in the module cannot be loaded.

  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.Assembly:GetTypes (bool)

Answer (score 19):

I had just the same problem in Visual Studio 2015. But [Utamaru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1868672/utamaru)'s solution worked for me.

Make a folder: Assets/Plugins where you put the *.dll file and add it as a reference.

To add a reference you highlight the Analyzers in the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio and under Project > Add Reference you can find your *.dll file located in Assets/Plugin by browsing to it.

[image: Add reference in Visual Studio 2015 part 1]
[image: Add reference in Visual Studio 2015 part 2]

Comment: I also had to restart Unity.

Answer (score 6):

For support in built versions, recommended to use one of following

- `Json.NET v13.0` [github.com/jilleJr/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity](https://github.com/jilleJr/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity#readme)
- `Json.NET v9.0` [github.com/SaladLab/Json.Net.Unity3D](https://github.com/SaladLab/Json.Net.Unity3D#readme)
- `Json.NET v8.0` [parentelement.com/assets/json_net_unity](https://www.parentelement.com/assets/json_net_unity)
- `Json.NET v7.0` [nuget.org/packages/Unity.Newtonsoft.Json/](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Newtonsoft.Json/)

Or if you dont require Newtonsoft.Json (Json.NET), here's some other alternatives *(all works in Unity, I've omitted libraries that don't, and there's a lot of 'em):*

- `OdinSerializer` [github.com/TeamSirenix/odin-serializer](https://github.com/TeamSirenix/odin-serializer#readme)
- `UTF8Json` [github.com/neuecc/Utf8Json](https://github.com/neuecc/Utf8Json#readme)
- `FastJSON` [assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/fastjson-27220](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/fastjson-27220)
- `UltimateJson` [assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/ultimate-json-60845](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/ultimate-json-60845)
- `SimpleJson` [wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON)
- `LitJson` [github.com/Mervill/UnityLitJson](https://github.com/Mervill/UnityLitJson#readme)
- `FullSerializer` [github.com/jacobdufault/fullserializer](https://github.com/jacobdufault/fullserializer#readme)
- `protobuf-net` [github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net#readme)

There is quite the table of candy to select from. *Choose well young padawan~*

Comment: `Json.NET v12.0 github.com/jilleJr/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity`
Helped me, thank you!

Comment: The `.unitypackage` from this release was the only one that worked for me: [SaladLab/Json.Net.Unity3D -> Json.Net 7.0.1](https://github.com/SaladLab/Json.Net.Unity3D/releases/tag/7.0.1.0). I was having issues getting the Unity Asset [ClaytonIndustries/QuickSave](https://github.com/ClaytonIndustries/QuickSave) to work in my Unity v2017.4.23f1.

Answer (score 4):

I have stumbled upon this project
https://github.com/SaladLab/Json.Net.Unity3D

> Newtonsoft Json.NET is a de facto standard JSON library in .NET ecosystem. But it doesn't support Unity3D, so it's a little bit hard to use JSON.NET just after getting Json.NET package. This package is for Unity3D programmers that need to use latest Json.NET in Unity3D.

Just import the unity [package](https://github.com/SaladLab/Json.Net.Unity3D/releases) and you are good to go.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use Asset Store to add the fabulous **newtonsoft.JSON** library named **JSON .NET For Unity** at the Store.

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/json-net-for-unity-11347

Answer (score 2):

Use simpleJson. Its free and gets the work done.

Copy the SimpleJSON.cs contents into a newly created file in your project and you're ready to go. If you want to be fancy -> create this new file in assets\plugins directory

http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

JSON.NET for Unity3D is available on the asset store; https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/11347

Comment: But it costs $25, while NewtonSoft Json.net is free through NuGet!

Comment: Yes, but the freely available version through NuGet isn't compatible. Hence why another version is available on the Unity store. Not sure why I've been downvoted here.

Comment: It says FREE so perhaps they changed it.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please atleast explain why the nuget package is not compatible if you want to plug a product

Answer (score 0):

If you adding reference to *.dll through IDE and after recompile IDE throws out, check if you have assembly definition. If so, you need to add it to Assembly References. It worked for me.  [Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUA9D.png)

Answer (score -5):

You need to add the dll to your projects references.

References >> Add Reference.

Comment: If I do that I get the message, that there already exists a reference to Newtonsoft.json and Newtonsoft is already in the reference list.