# Looking how to convert DataContractJsonSerializer to json.net

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, json.net

I am working in Unity and can't use System.Runtime.Serialization.Json. I have the following code I am trying to get to work using json.net. But not having much luck how to go about it. Any tips on what to check in the documentation would be appreciated.

```
using (var fs = new FileStream(jsonFile, FileMode.Open))
{
    var settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings();
    settings.UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true;

    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ConvNetJS.Network), settings);
    var test = serializer.ReadObject(fs) as ConvNetJS.Network;
}
```

ConvNetJS.Network is a small class

```
[DataContract]
public class Network
{
    public Network()
    {
        this.Layers = new List<Layer>();
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "layers")]
    public List<Layer> Layers
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

How would I go about this using json.net?

Comment: did you add the `using Newtonsoft.Json;` to the using section at the top of the class..? as well as Manually adding it's reference to the project references node..?

Comment: Are you looking for [Deserialize JSON from a file](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithJsonSerializerFromFile.htm)?  Or are you looking for [Adding Json.Net to a Unity3D project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398407/adding-json-net-to-a-unity3d-project)?

Comment: I added it using github.com/SaladLab/Json.Net.Unity3D. Can run the example. What I am after is converting the above code to using json.net. Sorry for not being more clear. Will try your " Deserialize JSON from a file" link tonight, thanks!

Comment: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithJsonSerializerFromFile.htm did the trick. Thanks!