# Parsing multidimensional arrays using JsonUtility

Tags: c#, json, multidimensional-array

I have a Unity C# application that needs to parse a JSON list of lists of floats.  Parsing a float or a list of floats is fine but a nested list fails:

```
var test_data = JsonUtility.FromJson<TEST_DATA>(@"{""a"":1,""b"":[1],""c"":[[1]],""d"":[1],""e"":[[1]]}");
Debug.Log("ToJson: " + JsonUtility.ToJson(test_data)); // {"a":1.0,"b":[1.0],"d":[1.0]}
```

1. From looking at the docs and other answers it appears I need to implement my own parser or use a third party library.
2. That there is not a way of implementing a custom method that JsonUtility will call for particular fields.

Are these two assertions correct?  Note the real data structure to parse is an object with many more fields and many levels of nested objects.

Comment: It seems that one can use real Newtonsoft Json.Net library in Unity (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398407/adding-json-net-to-a-unity3d-project)... That's probably the easiest route...

Comment: Thank you @AlexeiLevenkov , can you add as an answer please?