# Unity: how to implement a .dll

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am quite new to Unity and I am trying to implement an external dll with which I can then control a player object in my project. However, I get the following error messages and I really do not know how to fix this problem

> Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ide.rider@1.1.4\Rider\Editor\Discovery.cs(248,24):
> error CS0433: The type 'Registry' exists in both
> 'Microsoft.Win32.Registry, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>
> Assembly 'Assets/_dll/UsbSensorHelperPlaudertisch.dll' will not be loaded due to errors: Unable to resolve reference
> 'Newtonsoft.Json'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the
> current platform? Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin
> Inspector.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use `json.net` for Unity, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30398407/1997232).

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Nuget packages and check if you have installed the Newtonsoft.Json package with the correct version. 
If you have already installed the package, it seems that your package version is not compatible with your assembly (class library) version. Then you can uninstall the package and reinstall an older version compatible with your assembly.

Answer (score 0):

To install Nuget packages in Unity3D, the best way I found is to follow this guide :

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/visualstudio/cross-platform/unity-scripting-upgrade?view=vs-2019#add-packages-from-nuget-to-a-unity-project

In your case it's exactly the same package you need, but it works with others packages as well.